# Android EditText Focus

Tags: android, listener, android-edittext, setfocus

I have set a Listener for change in selection of spinner. In the listener I want to focus a EditText field. I have used the following code:

text_other_msg.setFocusable(true);

It is not working. I also tried with setFocusableInTouchMode. But none is working. How to focus a EditText?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try below code

```
text_other_msg.requestFocus();
```